# how to set accessible name for a QGraphicsScene?

Tags: qt, mouseclick-event, qgraphicsscene

I'm using QT. I want to set accessible name for a QGraphicsScene because at the mouse click I want to check whether witch graphics scene has been clicked?
Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each class that is derived from QObject(including QGraphicsScene) has following function to set a name for it:

```
void setObjectName ( const QString & name )
```

And you can retrieve this name with this function:

```
QString objectName () const
```